# Shape information lost after scuplting

Tags: mesh

I currently experiment on an eagle. The eagle from the beginning had a shape of feathers. After sculpting its body (which also changed a bit his original form), I lost the shape of the feathers at some parts of its body, as seen in the picture below. Is there a way to "multiply" the feathers that remained, to the rest of its body?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this, so in case anyone runs in this question, here is what I did:

I used an image (in my case an image of *scales*) as the texture of the Clay brush in *Sculpt Mode*.

For more information and further understanding of the process, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YWte1cqYBA&t=287s&ab_channel=GrantAbbitt) is the tutorial video that helped me.